# application login with facebook login

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook

I have an app with login page, and I want to make the application to work with "facebook login".
Can any one help me?

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Facebook documentation will be your best resource.

for websites: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

for mobile: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

There is also this framework which is provided specifically for iOS:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk