# Open facebook dialog for authentication instead of Installed facebook app in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to made a app that ask to authenticate for facebook login in dialog either if facebook application is installed in iphone or not installed.And if I log out the facebook then it should logout from facebook. I have used facebook-ios-sdk for facebook api my code is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _facebook=[[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appId andDelegate:self];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"])
    {
        _facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        _facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

**//login button tapped**

```
-(IBAction)Login
{
    NSLog(@"login called");

    if (![self connected])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection" message:@"Internet is not Connected" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];[alert release];
    }
    else
    {
        if (suggestion==nil)
        {
            suggestion=[[Suggestions alloc] initWithNibName:@"Suggestions" bundle:nil];
        }
        [suggestion setReqFlg:YES];

        if (![_facebook isSessionValid]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"sesssion invalid u have to login...");
            [_facebook authorize:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"valid and going on next page called graph API ");      

            [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=id,name" andDelegate:self];
            suggestion.parentView=self;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:suggestion animated:YES];
        }
    }
}



- (void)fbDidLogin
{
    NSLog(@"facebook did first login..");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[_facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[_facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];  
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"called gtraph from login in facebook ");
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=id" andDelegate:self];
    if (suggestion==nil)
    {
        suggestion=[[Suggestions alloc] initWithNibName:@"Suggestions" bundle:nil];
    }
    suggestion.parentView=self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:suggestion animated:YES];
}

- (void)fbDidLogout
{
    NSLog(@"logout");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBUserId"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Does I have to change in facebook.m file or there is another way to do this.Every time I clicked on login button should display facebook login dialog if facebook is logout and navigate to next view if facebook is login.Do not open facebook app installed in iphone for login purpose.

**Give your reviews or answers I really need it.
Thanks u!**

Comment: If I clicked on login button it goes to facebook app installed in my iphone for authentication.I want to show it in facebook dialog.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that apple doesn't let you log into facebook from your own application

Comment: It logins but uses facebook app I don't want to use it I want to use facebook dialog for login not facebook app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5000705/1439815

Comment: I have already used that it doesn't work like that

Answer (score 1):

its so simple go in facebook.m file, search with FBAppAuth and You got 3_4 result like:-

```
 [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

just change YES to NO like:-

```
 [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

change it in facebook.m only and compile and run you got fblogin dialog when you click on loginButton :)

**edit**

i got my login dialog on my app login page

[image: facebook login dialog]

Comment: Mr Nitin Gohel this is for safari not for facebook App if facebook app is installed on your iphone then it will not open dialog for authentication.

Comment: its for both i trying this code and implement on my own work and its working fine :-- read full method authorizewithFBAppAuth:NO OR YES

Comment: Pls install facebook app on your idevice and then check it on your device.

Comment: see my editable answer i just uplode my screenshot and in facebook.m file change each authorizeWithFBAppAuth=NO not only in one method its implement 2_3 place in facebook.m

Comment: No No i am also logout with this method:-
[[objappdelegate facebook] logout];